# Use es6 classes other than component (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, ecmascript-6

In React's official [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) (tic tac toe), three components are used: `Game`, `Board`, and `Square`.

Game contains an array of `squares` that can contain X, O and `null`: All three are primitive types.

My question: Is it an **accepted practice** to use es6 classes (not extending component because not rendering anything) to hold information primitives certainly cannot hold? The classes can also be inherited from other classes.

For example, can we store objects of `Piece` class in `squares` array and instead of X/O show `piece.name` in the square? And can we move a `piece` from `i` to `j` to reflect it on the board of squares?

Need to ask this for two reasons:

1. Almost all React examples revolve around components. I haven't yet seen classes used otherwise.
2. Inheritance is discouraged for components ([composition vs inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)), which I think would be needed to specialize `Piece` class in the example above.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you couldn't, but I can think of why you shouldn't. What you're trying to do I believe would be better accomplished using a functional stateless component to represent the `Piece`. The `Piece`'s properties would be given to it by a parent component's state, or a `redux` store. The `Piece` itself is just presentational. The logic for where it is should be in a higher component. I really don't see the need for a class here.

Comment: This question is likely subjective and maybe not answerable. In my experience, usually objects are used for state `{age: 25, name: 'John Doe'}`, classes are not used for state but for components as you said. See [state & lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) docs.

Comment: @styfle, agreed that objects can contain state but that does not address inheritance. A `Person` can have  `{age: 25, name: 'John Doe'}`, but it's extended class `Employee` should have the same fields plus some others. That is with OOP perspective. Just wanted to know how would we go about that in React. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks @KyleRichardson. "The Piece's properties would be given to it by a parent component's state". That's where my confusion is. Where and how those properties are stored? Object, class, something else? Definitely not component (functional or class), because nothing is being rendered, which is what components are for.

Comment: @TalhaAwan Their state, if they needed state relating to them directly, would be stored inside an object on the parent components state, or in a `store`. They might not even need state depending on what you want to do and likely don't. They could just be given props potentially. Their positioning would be determined by the state of the board. Their name, look, etc would be determined by what props they were created with.

Comment: @KyleRichardson, what I think you mean to say is that a component high in the hierarchy will contain `this.state.squares`. Is it? If so, my question is what will each element of square contain? As we want to store more than primitive values, should it be class, object or some other scheme? Please go ahead and answer if you like or ask me for further clarification. Not reached redux yet so I would prefer simple React.

Comment: If the answer I just provided is not what you're looking for, give me as much info as you can and I will try again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. I did not include any state updating mechanism, and this is rather conceptual, but I think you'll get the gist.

```
// holds the state of your board and calculates the view layer
class Board extends PureComponent {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        // create pieces for however you want the game to start
        this.pieces = {
            p1: new piece( "Lumberjack" ),
            p2: new piece( "Lumberjack" ),
            p3: new piece( "Lumberjack" ),
            p4: new piece( "Tree" ),
            p5: new piece( "Tree" ),
            p6: new piece( "Tree" )
        }

        // flatten for easy and speed of access
        const { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6 } = this.pieces;

        // initial state, this is what gets updated by this.setState method
        // to update the rendered view
        this.state ={
            squares: [
                [ p1, p2, p3 ],
                [ null, null, null ],
                [ p4, p5, p6 ]
            ]
        };
    }

    // render method that produces the view
    render() {
        const { squares } = this.state;
        const iLength = squares.length;
        let i, j jLength, components = [ ];

        // generate the Squares from this.state data
        for ( i = 0; i < iLength; i++ ) {
            jLength = squares[ i ].length;
            for ( j = 0; jLength; j++ ) {
                components.push( <Square piece={ squares[ i ][ j ] } /> );
            }
        }

        // render the Squares containing the pieces
        return (
            <div className="board">
                { components }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// piece constructor
function piece( name ) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

You'd end up with 9 squares on a board. One side would be Lumberjacks, the middle would be clear, and there'd be so scared Tree's on the otherside.

Comment: You used piece constructor, why not class? Let's say we want to move the pieces on the board as well. Lumberjacks and Tree can move differently but both cannot go outside the board. That's where I think of a `Piece` class having `move()` method. `Lumberjack` and `Tree` inherit from `Piece`. If we `move()` Lumberjack it calls super.move() to confirm it's not going out the table then checks its own logic and then finally moves if allowed. Something to this effect. Thanks for the answer. Really appreciate!

Comment: You could just put a move method on your board that takes parameters and store the parameters on the piece how it is now. Seems like an easier solution to me.

Comment: Yes `move()` would be in `Board` and `isMoveLegal(src, dest)` in `Piece`. Will still need a class for `Piece` I think. Why not use a class with methods is what I don't get :) Because constructor is essentially doing the same thing. Thanks for your time and answer. Accepting it.

Comment: That `isMoveLegal` method could also be on the board. You take the `src` from the piece position in the game which is in the `board` state and the dest would be calculated by the parameters provided by the piece inside the `move` method. The `isMoveLegal` is called inside of `move` and if it is not legal it returns false or calls itself to calculate another move. Just a thought.